# git-svn HEAD differs from master

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Sometimes I end up in following state, where the HEAD is not to be shown on the same commit as the master.

I suppose the HEAD must be checked out and following commits must go to HEAD.   But how do I level both pointer on the same commit?

[image]

Comment: Seams like I'm in this "detached head" again. Sometimes plain checkout master helps, but not now.

Comment: Read all about the in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716

Comment: Will do, but can you explain me the thing that happened as described in second comment to Niekname answer?

Comment: Yes i can will do it in few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sometimes I end up in following state, where the `HEAD` is not to be shown on the same commit as the master.

As mentioned in the comment above - [read all about `HEAD` here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716).

To answer your questions:

Everytime you change your repository state your `HEAD` is modified and is updated and pointing to the current commit.

`detached HEAD` is when the HEAD is pointing to any commit **other** than the latest commit.

In the described link you can read all about it and there is a detailed explanation what is head which im not going describe here.

---

> Can you explain me this?
>
> I changed some file being on `HEAD`, then I have `checkout master` and did `git svn rebase` which failed as there was the file changed.
>
> So I have reverted the changes and did git svn rebase still on master.
> The result `HEAD`, master, git-svn are on the same commit.
>
> I actually did nothing and it is fixed now? How is that?

---

Lets break it into pieces and ill explain each piece:

> I changed some file being on `HEAD`

**You can't do anything directly on HEAD**. `HEAD` is simply a reference to commit. Its a simple text file which store the SHA-1 of the commit which your current branch is now pointing to.

---

> then I have `checkout master`

Now your `HEAD` is pointing to the latest commit on master.

---

> ...  did `git svn rebase` ...  reverted the changes

Your `HEAD` is back to its original value before the rebase - no changes should appear. (don't confuse it with the `git revert` command)

---

> The result `HEAD`, master, git-svn are on the same commit.
> I actually did nothing and it is fixed now? How is that?

As explained above - look on it like this. You started to go on a walk (in this metaphor `HEAD` is storing how far you are from the point you started to walk). you walked here and there (your rebase that you tried to do ) and then you decided you don't like the walk and you went back home. (you reverted the rebase).  Now `HEAD` is back in its original value since no "work" has been committed.

Comment: The question is why the `git checkout master` and `git svn rebase` didn't align them on the first try? If I'm getting it correctly it should work right away. I often have this issue and I need to play with the IDE for a while to get it right. Maybe it is some rendering issue of Intellij IDE's git viewer.

Comment: Nope, first of all you need to understand what is a rebase. rebase change the history line of your branch. since you go back in time and re-write the commits again your HEAD is changed. Once you revert the change its aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you have a branch 'git-svn' which is 1 commit ahead of master and your HEAD is on that commit.
You could just checkout the 'git-svn' branch and then push/merge it into master, if that is what you want?

Comment: I tried to cherry-pick the Revert "Removed.... commit. So I switched to master, git-svn rebase then I did the cherry-picking and after that I did dcommit. Some rebase should fix it then right?

Comment: Can you explain me this? I changed some file being on HEAD, then I have checkout master and did git svn rebase which failed as there was the file changed. So I have reverted the changes and did git svn rebase still on master. The result HEAD, master, git-svn are on the same commit. I actually did nothing and it is fixed now? How is that?